# Use of HTML tags for code formatting causes the improper code formatting warning to be triggered

Tags: discussion, bug, code-formatting

On SO, if you try to post a question or answer with code in it that is formatted using HTML `<code></code>` tags, you trigger the "Your post has improperly formatted code in it" warning; this is a problem if you have a *long* code snippet in your post, as the 4-spaces-per-line Markdown code formatting adds up.  (Before you say 'minimize your example!', some things simply cannot be reproduced or demonstrated with a *short* code example...)

Why would using HTML instead of Markdown for code formatting always trigger this warning?  Do `<code></code>` tags have a different effect than the Markdown four-spaces convention?

Comment: How large is your code sample?  If it's large enough that you really can't format it with spaces, I rather doubt that it's a *minimal* reproducible example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<code></code>` is for *inline* code formatting, which for a large code block is definitely improper formatting. Try `<pre><code></code></pre>` instead.